# Primefaces SelectBooleanCheckbox with confirmation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to show confirmation dialog on select/unselect checkbox in primefaces. I have tried to

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckBox value="#{myBean.checkBoxValue}">
    <p:confirm message="Are you sure?"/>
</p:selectBoooleanCheckBox>
```

but it doesn't work since selectBooleanCheckBox is not Confirmable. Is there any workaround to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

One way is to create your own confirmDialog like

```
<p:confirmDialog widgetVar="myOwnConfirmDialog" message="Confirm ?">
    <p:commandButton value          =   "Yes"
                     action         =   "#{myBean.checkConfirmedAction}"
                     oncomplete     =   "PF('myOwnConfirmDialog').hide()"/>

    <p:commandButton value          =   "No" 
                     action         =   "#{myBean.checkCancelledAction}"
                     oncomplete     =   "PF('checkConfirmwdgt').toggle(); PF('myOwnConfirmDialog').hide()"/>
</p:confirmDialog>
```

and then use ***onchange*** event to open the confirmDialog:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox    value="#{myBean.checkBoxValue}" 
                            onchange="PF('myOwnConfirmDialog').show()" 
                            widgetVar="checkConfirmwdgt">
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

**EDIT:**
I made a typo and a mistake on my answer. The typo was actually using `<p:confirm>` inside  `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` (you are right, selectBooleanCheckbox isnt confirmable.)
The mistake was that `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox>` doesn't fires onclick, but only onblur, onchange and onfocus. Using onchange will work.

Comment: Nice idea - but it doesn´t work. :-(
The component is still not confirmable (PF 5.3) so the tag is not allowed.... what is most annoying is that even "onclick" is not fired .... so all my ideas to solve this manually are lost.

Comment: i edited the answer and tested it. Now it should work.

Comment: Okay.... nice. So the trick was to use "onblur" or "onchange" instead of "onclick". Sad that PF doesn´t allow "onclick" or implement "Confirmable".

Answer (score 0):

I solved it a different way - didn´t want to wait till PrimeFaces implements the Interface.
I´m displaying two "commandButton"s - only one of them is rendered dependent on state. They are enclosed by a form - or you can use a named panel ("selectProductUsageForm" in my example) which is updated via AJAX. The first one is representing the active (toggled) state - the second the untoggled state.

The solution was to mimic the display behaviour - which Primefaces encapsulates in the CSS-class "ui-state-active" (theme.css). I copied the contents of the CSS-class to my own CSS-class "man-ui-state-active" and assigned it to the first button.

```
 <h:form id="selectProductUsageForm" 
    rendered="#{productManager.mayEditSelected}">
   <span class="productGroupUsageBtnContainer">


    <p:commandButton 
        value="#{msg['product.inUseByGroup']} (#{login.currentUser.group.name})" styleClass="man-ui-state-active"
        icon="ui-icon-check"
        action="#{productManager.toggleCurrentProductGroupUsage}" 
        rendered="#{productManager.currentProductGroupUsage}" update="selectProductUsageForm">
            <p:confirm message="Are you sure?"/>
    </p:commandButton>
    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['product.notInUseByGroup']} (#{login.currentUser.group.name})" 
        icon="ui-icon-close"
        action="#{productManager.toggleCurrentProductGroupUsage}" 
        rendered="#{not productManager.currentProductGroupUsage}" update="selectProductUsageForm">
            <p:confirm message="Are you sure?"/>
    </p:commandButton>
    </span>
   </h:form>
```

CSS

```
.ui-button.man-ui-state-active {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    background-color: #d9d9d9 \9;
    background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show a notification(info, alert,...) on a change of the checkbox. Do this :

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckBox value="#{myBean.checkBoxValue}"
  onchange="if(!confirm('Your warning or information message here!!!')) 
   return false">
   <p:ajax listener="#{myBean.yourMethodHere()}" 
      update="theComponentYouWantToUpdate" />
</p:selectBoooleanCheckBox>
```